# Lightsabers with extendable hilts

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, lightsaber

Are there any examples (preferably in canon but Legends is also acceptable) of a lightsaber featuring an extending hilt? What I'm looking for is perhaps some kind of telescoping mechanism such that the saber can have a standard-ish length hilt which extends out to be more like a naginata/nagamaki or similar real-world weapon.

I'm not looking for a folding hilt, such as with "Dark Rey's" folding saber staff in The Rise of Skywalker.

Comment: so basically you're asking for an extendable lightsabre hilt

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber_pike/Legends

Comment: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/7/7b/Sith_warrior_lightsaber_pike_bts.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20160329235639

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Long-handle_lightsaber

Comment: @shanu That's exactly what I'm after.

Comment: @Valorum those look like good examples of long handled lightsabers, although I'm specifically looking for ones which can swap between a short or long haft

Comment: Close voter, list questions are fine as long as they're well constrained. In this instance, there can't possibly be more than a few examples.

Comment: Probably a good thing Mel Brooks didn't think of this for _Spaceballs_...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be looking for something like [Senya's lightsaber pike](https://swtorista.com/weapon/senyas-lightsaber-pike) from *Star Wars: The Old Republic*. It doesn't compact as much as a standard lightsaber, being more like a double-bladed lightsaber in length, but it telescopes from a more compact form into a longer pike-like form.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I was hoping existed! I'll leave the question open a bit longer just in case anyone else has a more comprehensive answer or a variety of examples

Answer (score 3):

I think sabrecanes should qualify.

The primary purpose of the sabercane was to act as a concealed weapon, a convenient place to hide a lightsaber. Two of the sabercanes observed, Haazen's and Tera Sinube's, both featured the lightsaber connected to the shaft of the cane at the emitter, necessitating the removal of the shaft to wield the lightsaber.

Though it was used for concealing the lightsabre, it could be later be removed and then use it as a normal lightsabre, so it qualifies as a an 'extention' for the lightsabre. [Fandom sabercane](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sabercane)